# Looping through non-contiguous rows selected with a criteria

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post in SO. As you know I am not a professional programmer, just a regular office worker who does some VBA from time to time to get his job done faster.

I would like to loop over a range of cells using VBA that contains a specific flag value in one of its columns. These ranges are non-contiguous since we select the ranges with the successive flag value, and this value changes randomly in each row.

For example in the table below, how could we loop three times (since there are three non-contiguous ranges with successive -1 flags) selecting the first three rows in the first iteration, the 5th and 6th rows in the second run, and selecting the 8th row in the third iteration?

```
+-------+---------+------+
| Index |  Value  | Flag |
+-------+---------+------+
|     1 | 0.43534 |   -1 |
|     2 | 0.24366 |   -1 |
|     3 | 0.23654 |   -1 |
|     4 | 0.56854 |    0 |
|     5 | 0.97867 |   -1 |
|     6 | 0.35678 |   -1 |
|     7 | 0.47845 |    0 |
|     8 | 0.74567 |   -1 |
+-------+---------+------+
```

Comment: Everything is looping whether at a lower-level, or a higher-level. Even in databases, there are initial loops through each record. The key is how you deal with the loop and can you do everything you need to do in one loop, without relooping. If you want to perform a calculation on a group within a loop, then consider `Do Loop While`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @MacroMarc. Could you possibly share some web resources or keywords in which I could read more about looping, in the context of it being at a higher or lower level, especially in how should I deal with the looping algorithm to do everything in a single loop? Sorry if this is a basic computer science question, as I am still trying to learn the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will give result in message box specifying all the ranges with `Flag = -1`. As per your sample data image, output will be `$C$2:$C$4`, `$C$6:$C$7`, `$C$9`.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range, fCell As Range, tempRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim isNegative As Boolean

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")      'change Sheet2 to your data sheet
    isNegative = False

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row    'last row with data in Column C

        For Each cel In .Range("C2:C" & lastRow + 1)  'loop through each cell in Column C
            If cel.Value = -1 Then      'check if value is -1
                If Not isNegative Then
                    Set fCell = cel
                    isNegative = True
                End If
            Else                        'if not then set range
                If isNegative Then
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng = .Range(fCell, cel.Offset(-1, 0).Address)
                    Else
                        Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(fCell, cel.Offset(-1, 0).Address))
                    End If
                    isNegative = False
                End If
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
    For Each tempRng In rng.Areas 'loop through all ranges with -1
        MsgBox tempRng.Address
        'write your code here
    Next tempRng
End Sub
```

> Here's a brief explanation on Booloean variable `isNegative` used in the code.
>
> `isNegative` is used to maintain flag whether last cell value in range `.Range("C2:C" & lastRow + 1)` was `-1` or not and is set to `FALSE` at the beginning. When first `-1` is countered then `isNegative` is set to `TRUE` and `fCell` is assigned the corresponding cell address. Till loop encounters `-1`, `isNegative` will remain `TRUE`. When a cell with value not equal to `-1` is encountered, range is set using `rng` from `fCell` to current cell using `Set rng = .Range(fCell, cel.Offset(-1, 0).Address)` if only one cell with `-1` is encountered else `Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(fCell, cel.Offset(-1, 0).Address))` if more than one cell with `-1` are encountered.
>   When second or more successive cells with value not equal to `-1` are encountered then nothing happens. Above process is repeated when next cell with value `-1` is encountered.

Comment: Mrig, thank you so much for this detailed answer, I did not realize that the problem will be solved in just a few hours with this much answer. SO is truly amazing, with its talented community willing to help others new to programming.

Comment: If you still have time, I would like to ask on how did you arrive at the solution? Not necessarily a detailed explanation, perhaps just a crude logic diagram that would show the flow of data and guide me to dig deeper and research the method used. (I am especially confused about the use of `isNegative` and `isRange` boolean variables)

Comment: @EmmanD. - I've added explanation for `isNegative`. `isRange` is not required, used it for testing and forgot to remove it from code while uploading the answer. Let me know if anything is still not clear.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Everything's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You would still loop as normal, but use an If statement to check if column 3 (C) has a -1, such as:

```
Dim i as Long

For i = 2 to 9 'Assumes 1 is a header row, despite 1-8 being counted
    If Cells(i,3).Value= -1 Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using something like  `do while flag=-1`.

Or instead use the condition `if Flag(index)=Flag(index+1) then *do something*`, because I think something more complex would require designing a module class.